# How can i send a token using retrofit

Tags: java, retrofit

Hello guys im trying to send a token in order to get a list of subjects so i'm actually getting the token and the server it is allowing me to log in but now to the same server with the token that im getting i need to send back the token so i can get the list of a subjects also i need to send to the server an idcareer because depending the occupation that the user select in the registration process the server will return a specific list for that specific career, i know i need a post

```
public interface APIInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Field("user") String user,
                              @Field("password") String password);

    @GET("/careers")
    Call<List<Carrers>> getCarreras();

    @GET("/postgraduates")
    Call<List<Post_Grade>> getPostGrade();

    @GET("/occupations")
    Call<List<SpinnerOcupation>>getOcupations();

    //Registration
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/saveuser")
    Call<ResponseBody> createUser(@Body RegisterModel json);

    @GET("/universities")
    Call<List<SpinnerUniversity>>getUniversity();

    @GET("/find/period")
    Call<ResponseBody> getPeriod(@Header("Authorization") String authtoken);

    @GET("/subjects")
    Call<List<Subjects>> getSubjects (@Query("idcareer")String subjects);

}
```